# C programming in code blocks getting error of undefined reference to 'WinMain'

Tags: c, codeblocks, linker-errors, undefined-reference

I am trying to open a video file in c program in codeblocks but i am getting error ''Undefined Reference to 'WinMain'. I am using codeblocks 16.1 and with opencv installed. i tried to add the libraries mentioned in other answers but i am unable to get output. Help will be highly appriciated

Comment: Does your code define `WinMain`?  Does it define `main` instead?  Windows is peculiar — not all C programs have/use `main`; for some modes of operation, you are expected to write `WinMain` or other specialized names (`_tmain`?) instead.

Comment: Can you please show us the relevant code?

Comment: #include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdafx.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <avifmt.h>
#include <direct.h>
#include <tchar.h>

int Winmain() (int argc, char* argv[])
{
   FILE *fp1,*fp2;
   int c;
   fp1=fopen("C:/Users/Asghar/Desktop/aoun.avi",'rb');
   fp2=fopen("C:/Users/Asghar/Desktop/result.mp4",'wb');
   c=getc(fp1);
   while(c!=EOF){
    putc(c,fp2);
    c=getc(fp1);

   }
   fclose(fp1);
   fclose(fp2);
return 0;
}

Comment: Jonathan Leffler I include then i get expected error const  char* restricts but argument is of type int

Answer (score 1):

You have `Winmain()`, while the system looks for `WinMain`.